# javascript setInterval not firing

Tags: ajax, setinterval

I have a long running database update that I want to report on while it is happening.
I prime the interval time to fire at 
I have seen lots of examples of problems with setInterval and it looks simple, but I cannot get it to fire with this code. The checkSaveStatus code pulls back a status report that tells how many rows have been saved. I will enhance it once I to display the results once I can get the basic functionality working.

I am beginning to suspect that this may have something to do with the way I am handling the Ajax call.

```
var checkTimer;
function checkSaveStatus() {
    var saveStatus = ajaxCall("WebServices/FLSAService.asmx/CheckFLSASaveStatus");
    if (saveStatus == null) {
        clearInterval(checkTimer);
        return;
    }
    log('saveStatus: ' + saveStatus.InputCount + '/' + saveStatus.ResultCount + ':' + saveStatus.SaveComplete, 'FLSA');
    if (saveStatus.SaveComplete) {
        reportSaveComplete = true;
        clearInterval(checkTimer);
    }
}

checkTimer = window.setInterval(checkSaveStatus, 1000);
... make an asynchronous Ajax call that takes a long time to complete
... the checkSaveStatus code doesn't fire until the Ajax call completes
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you cannot return a value from your ajax because it is asynchronous. The way that is handled is through callbacks. So this section of code:

```
var saveStatus = ajaxCall("WebServices/FLSAService.asmx/CheckFLSASaveStatus");
if (saveStatus == null) {
    clearInterval(checkTimer);
    return;
}
```

Is more than likely not operating properly. It is hard to say without seeing the `ajaxCall` function, but you are probably not getting the result you intended to get. That left hand side assignment is not going to reflect anything which would be asynchronous. As a result it will either be what the default value is returned from `ajaxCall`, or it will be `undefined`, which when compared with `== null` will be true, and in turn will clear your interval and return.